# Isn't a struct with a reference data member a literal type?

Tags: c++, constexpr

, I don't understand the following behavior:

```
#include <memory>

template <int Index, typename Type>
struct position {
    using value_type = Type;

    template <typename TT>
    constexpr position( TT& val )
        : value{ val }
    {
    }

    static constexpr int index = Index;
    Type &               value;
};

int main()
{

    constexpr double d = 3.14;
    constexpr auto p1=position<3, const double>(d).value; // ok
    constexpr auto p2=position<3, const double>(d); // error
}
```

why `position<3, double>(3.14).value`  can be a constant expression while `position<3, double>( 3.14 )` is not?

I understand that the compiler would like the "position::value" data member to be a const reference, but why, isn't a reference a literal type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't a struct with a reference data member a literal type?

Yes, such a struct is a literal type.

`position<3, const double>(d)` is not a constant expression because its member `value` does not refer to a *permitted result of a constant expression*, because the referent of `value` (i.e. `d`) is neither an object with static storage duration nor a function.

[[expr.const]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6):

> A *constant expression* is [...] or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression,
> - [...]
>
> An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if it is an object with static storage duration [...], or it is a function.